# Is there a way for MongoDB to return which IDs were successfully replaced in a BulkWrite?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to write some C# library code that will replace documents in MongoDB, something like this:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<ThingUpdateResult>> UpdateAsync(
    [NotNull] IReadOnlyList<Thing> things, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (things == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(things));

    var writeModels = things
        .Select(i => new ReplaceOneModel<Thing>(
            new ObjectFilterDefinition<Thing>(new {i.Id}), i));

    var result = await _collection
        .BulkWriteAsync(writeModels, new BulkWriteOptions {IsOrdered = false}, cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Problem:
    var results = result.SuccessfulReplacements // There's no such thing, only ProcessedRequests and Upserts
        .Select(i => new ThingUpdateResult(i.Id.AsString, updated: true))
        .ToArray();

    return results;
}
```

I'm trying to return a collection of results where each result contains the ID of the document and a boolean indicating whether it was successfully updated. For example, if `things` contained a document that doesn't exist in MongoDB, I'd give it an outcome of `false`.

However... `result` doesn't contain any of that information; it only gives me a count of matches. Is there a way to find out *which* documents matched and which didn't?

**Edit**: just realized I need to do the same thing for deletes, so I imagine the situation there will be similar...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible since the WriteResult will return only the # of matched/updated/upserted and not their ID's.

I believe you will need to write a small function to:

- query the object
- save id/ value of some other property that will be modified
- execute the update
- query again
- compare the result